# How to create a new tmux window with same pane layout?

Tags: tmux

Is it possible to create a new tmux window with the same panes layout as the current window?

Comment: Please expand on "duplicate" and "preserving panes": do you mean duplicating everything, all the way down (creating new pseudo terminals and starting new processes in them)?  Or creating a new window that shows the *exact* same panes, with the same pseudo-terminals and already-running processes?

Comment: I mean creating a new window with the same panes layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tmux` does not have a built-in feature to do that.

## Scripting

What `tmux` does have is many simpler [commands](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tmux.1.html#COMMANDS) that can be called either within `tmux` or externally, eg. from the command line or a shell script. Most relevant to your needs is `list-windows`:

> ```
>  list-windows [-a] [-F format] [-t target-session]
>                (alias: lsw)
>          If -a is given, list all windows on the server.  Otherwise,
>          list windows in the current session or in target-session.  For
>          the meaning of the -F flag, see the FORMATS section.
> ```

The output from this includes the layout of each window, so a script could parse that information and send `tmux` further commands (`new-window`, `split` etc.) to create another window with the exact same layout.

## 3rd-party tools

As an alternative to writing the whole script, you could use one of several tools that other `tmux` users have already created, that simplify setting up sessions/layouts.  Each of the following allows a layout to be described in YAML:

- [Teamocil](https://github.com/remiprev/teamocil)
- [Tmuxinator](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator)
- [tmuxp](https://github.com/tmux-python/tmuxp)

From the [Teamocil README](https://github.com/remiprev/teamocil/blob/master/README.md#user-content-custom-window-layout):

> You can grab the layout for the current window by running this command:
>
> ```
>   tmux list-windows -F "#{window_active} #{window_layout}" | grep "^1" | cut -d " " -f 2
> ```
>
> You can then use the result as the layout key for any Teamocil window object.
>
> ```
> windows:
>   - name: sample-two-uneven-panes
>     layout: 00c7,158x38,0,0[158x9,0,0,37,158x28,0,10,39]
>     panes:
>       - echo foo
>       - echo bar
> ```